# RecyclerView on drop

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I have `RecyclerView` Drag & Drop feature, but I'd like to do some calculations onDrop. When I put my `expensiveFunction()` in `onMove()` it's triggered at every position change until the drag is over. That's a big overkill. Is there a way to trigger function on drag end?

```
val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback)
itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)

private var simpleCallback = object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP.or(ItemTouchHelper.DOWN), 0) {
    override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
        val startPosition = viewHolder.absoluteAdapterPosition
        val endPosition = target.absoluteAdapterPosition

        Collections.swap(itemList, startPosition, endPosition)
        recyclerView.adapter?.notifyItemMoved(startPosition, endPosition)

        expensiveFunction()

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add a touch up event and do it there if there has been a move since last touch down event. `setOnTouchListener` and a boolean flag set inside `onMove`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could override `onSelectedChanged()` which get called when the `ViewHolder` swiped or dragged by the `ItemTouchHelper`.

To catch the drop action examine the `actionState` value to be `ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE`:

```
override fun onSelectedChanged(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, actionState: Int) {
    super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState)
    when (actionState) {
        // when the item is dropped
        ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "Item is dropped")
        }
    }

}
```